# How can I set the height of a sticky element?

Tags: html, css, height, sticky

This is a simple example of sticky element, but I was wondering why I cant set a height to the sticky element (the green block).

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
   /* position: fixed; */
}

.btn {
    background: green;
    position: sticky;
     height: 50px; /* why does not work?!! */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='items'>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
            <div>hello world </div>
        </div>

        <button class='btn'>+</button>
    </div>
```

I removed the `position: fixed` but still not working!

Comment: It's because you gave the container 'position: fixed;'. If you leave that out, your button will have the specified height. Of course it all depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: still dont show the 50px height :(

Comment: It did, but you changed the height of your container class from `height: 40%;` to `height: 30vh;` in the above code.

Comment: because i want a scrollable container (that has a sticky block width height of 50px on its bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Snapshot of your snipped]

Look at the picture, this is a snapshot that I took while inspecting your snippet, as you can see the green bar has its complete height that you assigned to it, but some how it is not showing the complete height.

[image: Another snapshot]

This is another snapshot, that I took while running your snippet on full page. Here it is clearly visible that the green bar is using its assigned height (50px).

Although the way that you're styling your markup is not correct, you're keeping a sticky element within another fixed element. What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: it is showing the complete height as you can see from the 2nd image, when I ran your snippet in full page. And as far as I can tell the way you're trying to place this sticky element within another fixed element, doesn't look okay. You must try and update your markup so, that you don't fall into such a messy situation, otherwise going forward you might face more issues difficult to figure out because of wrong CSS and HTML combination. Please design your markup wisely and then use CSS to give life your design.

Comment: i changed it but it not working

Comment: You've made your container block a flex item, some how that flex properties are interfering with the sticky item. I tried removing flex from your container and the sticky item started showing fully. By the way why have you applied flex on the container? Because I don't see any need for applying flex on that item. Anyways your sticky item will come after the items holder, you only have one block holding multiple sub items and then this sticky button, why flex on the parent then?

Comment: @AminSanei I see some issues with your design, I mean your HTML and the way you're forcing CSS on to it, to make things work. Please think first what you need and then only apply CSS properties to a well formed HTML markup.